# using region based memory management in c

Tags: c, memory-management

Is there any documentation about region based memory management in c? without using any library (for region based memory management).

Where it teaches how to allocate regions and them store any data structure(for example linked list) in it and them destroy the region which cleans up the whole data structure instead of freeing memory of each node

Comment: This form of memory management is common in embedded systems with limited resources. It is straightforward to implement with care for the housekeeping details. Use `malloc()` to allocate large pools. Return pointers into the pool as needed. Keep careful track of everything. Use `free()` when the pool is to be emptied. But there are pitfalls. Outside of a classroom, I would look for a suitable library to leverage their hard learned lessons about where the sharp edges are.

Comment: what purpose would this serve, it is against most idioms of mid/high level programing.

Comment: You should search for "memory pool"

Comment: It is more about usage logic than implementation (which is incredibly simple, compared to every other method). In ideal case, you have just one stack - you can take memory from it, but it must be returned in reverse order (or 'free everything that was allocated after this one' thing). Sometimes this approach is good, especially in very memory-limited cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory allocation generally requires OS intervention.  A user-space program written in C can't use memory unless it has been made available to it via a platform-specific method (usually some virtual memory space expansion such as mmap() or brk).  C defines malloc() as the standard way to do this.  You can malloc() one very large region and carve it up in any way you see fit.  When you are done, you only need to free() one region.  Alternatively you can use your platform specific method of obtaining new memory and then release that.